# How do I template with Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I initially had this done via PHP includes, but React started giving me problems once I started nesting variables. This means that now I have giant containers of returns. For instance...

```
if (this.state.transitiontime){
return (
<div id="stuff">
//lots of html content//
</div>
);}
```

What would be the best way to separate the `//lots of html content//` into a separate file?

When I did it in PHP I did like so...

```
if (this.state.transitiontime){
return (
<div id="stuff">
<?php includes('htmlcontent.php');?>
</div>
);}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use Components you've written in ReactJS. For example you will be able to include your Component "SomeComponent" when using JSX like this:

```
if (this.state.transitiontime){
return (
<div id="stuff">
   <SomeComponent />
</div>
);}
```

Take a look at this: [ReactJS Multiple Components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html)

Comment: So would I have to add `ReactDOM.render(<SomeComponent />, document.getElementById('stuff'));` somewhere? Or is that already implicit in the main component?

Comment: When you've added your <App /> to the DOM you can easily render other Components inside your <App /> components render method - if this was your question. I think the right way would be to render your main App-Component and then to render child components inside your App.

Comment: Take a look at the first example in the link I've given to you. You see the case you are talking about. You will render the Main Component to your Dom and every children inside the render() method of your Main Component.